# Does a Completion Handler end the function?

Tags: swift, completionhandler

Perhaps I do not understand the concept of a completion handler, but I have a function like so;

```
func someFunction(completion: @escaping (Bool, LoginError?) -> Void) {
    self.checkDevice() { allowed, error in
       if let e = error {
          completion(false, e)
       }
        completion(true, nil)
    }
}
```

While being light on what `checkDevice()` does, the basic premise is that it performs an asynchronous network call, and returns either *true* with no error (nil), or returns *false* with an error.

When I run this code, I am finding that the completion handler is being called twice.  It sends a completion as a tuple (as `false, error`) and also as (`true, nil`).  I've done some debugging and there seems to be no manner in which `someFunction()` is called twice.

I was of the belief that once a **completion** is sent, the function would end.  In my test case, I am forcing an error from `checkDevice()`, which should result in me sending the completion as (`false, error`), but I am seeing both (`false, error`) and (`true, nil`).  Does a completion not immediately end the function?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  A completion handler is just a closure you can call, being named "completion" doesn't give it any special properties

Comment: Just put the second `completion(true, nil)` call in the `else` clause of the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A completion handler does not end a function. The typical way to end a function is to insert a `return`.

See comment re: your specific case

Comment: In your case, it is possible that your `self.checkDevice()` could be returning multiple times so that your completion block is hit multiple times. My suspicion is that you may have something inside the `self.checkDevice` function with the same presumption that the completion handler ends the function.

Comment: This answers the question, then!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

> I was of the belief that once a completion is sent, the function would end.

No, why would that be? When you call this function it’s like calling any other function. The *name* has no magic power.

Rewrite it like this:

```
func someFunction(completion: @escaping (Bool, LoginError?) -> Void) {
    self.checkDevice() { allowed, error in
        if let e = error {
            completion(false, e)
            return // *
        }
        completion(true, nil)
    }
}
```

Actually, I should mention that this is a poor way to write your completion handler. Instead of taking two parameters, a Bool and an Optional LoginError to be used only if the Bool is `false`, it should take *one* parameter — a Result, which carries both whether we succeeded or failed and, if we failed, what the error was:

```
func someFunction(completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {
    self.checkDevice() { allowed, error in
        completion( Result {
            if let e = error { throw e }
        })
    }
}
```

As you can see, using a Result as your parameter allows you to respond much more elegantly to what happened.

Indeed, `checkDevice` itself could pass a Result into *its* completion handler, and then things would be even more elegant (and simpler).

Comment: Thank you for this reply.  I appreciate the detail.  Is there a best practice in a team-based environment for following this mentality?  I.E. For any new developer, Result is now yet another class that said developer would have to follow and understanding.  As compared to a tuple of Bool, LoginError (which could be considered an Error), that it would be clearer to someone unfamiliar with the code, would it not?

Comment: In my view, Result is _much_ clearer. Instead of two parameters whose meaning has to be guessed at, we have _one_ parameter, an enum whose cases are `.success` and `.failure` (along with a payload such as the case of an error enum in case of failure). What could be clearer than that? And _extracting_ that information from the Result is so elegant and simple, much better than testing an Optional for nil or a Bool for true.

Comment: Thanks, @matt.  I've started working with a team and am trying to understand "best practices."  I get the sense that the more custom classes I create, the more work I'm creating for the team by them having to dig through what those classes mean.  But the project I'm working on has many custom classes as is, so I understand the perspective you are providing.  Thank you!

Comment: I have reviewed and implemented your suggestion and certainly see a difference in clarity.  Thank you for sharing this.  This was a big learning lesson and help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider including parameter names (for reference). And the completion should only be called once. You can do that using `return` or by using a full `if-else` conditional.

```
func someFunction(completion: @escaping (_ done: Bool, _ error: LoginError?) -> Void) {

    checkDevice() { (allowed, error) in

        if let e = error {
            completion(false, e)
        } else {
            completion(true, nil)
        }

    }

}

func someFunction(completion: @escaping (_ done: Bool, _ error: LoginError?) -> Void) {

    checkDevice() { (allowed, error) in

        if let e = error {

            completion(false, e)
            return

        }

        completion(true, nil)

    }

}
```

By giving parameters names, when calling the function, you can now reference the signature to denote the meanings of its parameters:

```
someFunction { (done, error) in

    if let error = error {
        ...
    } else if done {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, @bsod.  I appreciate the detail on this!